# DiskPart cannot format an offline volume

Tags: windows-10-v1607, diskpart

Previously it was all right buy a few days ago, I couldn't create a Windows To Go drive because all methods are failing. Then I tried to do the stuff on own before I notidec this:

```
DISKPART>sel dis 2
DISKPART>clean
DISKPART>cre par pri size=350
DISKPART>cre par pri
// So far nothing is wrong
DISKPART>for fs=ntfs unit=4096 quick
Error: Argument Error // What the hell???
DISKPART>onl vol
DISKPART>for fs=ntfs unit=4096 quick
100% Completed 
// Attempt to recreate the issue
DISKPART>off vol
DISKPART>for fs=ntfs unit=4096 quick
Error: Argument Error // So it is
DISKPART>exi
```

I suppose there's some system services going wrong.
Is there anything wrong with my computer OS? Windows 10 version 1607 (10.0.14393.586)

Edit: Please note that I am having problem formatting an offline **volume**, *not* an offline **disk**. Being unable to format an offline **disk** is very normal but when it comes to a **volume** it's abnormal.

Comment: That's normal. You can't format an offline disk.

Comment: @DavidPostill Take note it's a **volume** instead of a **disk**